what openOCD does to spike while debugging a program with spike?
My initial aim is to understand how debug mode works to design the debug mode of a CPU. I am following the guidelines of the riscv-isa-sim repo to debug a program. The only difference is creating a log while I am debugging. I used the same commands in the tutorial. I analyzed the log and eliminated the loop parts. It is the first several debugging parts explained below(there are many in the continuation of the log file but I didn't include it. I didn't include the actual program log too. I started writing it till entering debug rom.)
starting =>
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000800 (0x00c0006f)
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000080c (0x0ff0000f)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000810 (0x7b241073) c1970_dscratch0 0x0000000000000000
looping =>
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000814 (0xf1402473) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000818 (0x10802023) mem 0x0000000000000100 0x00000000
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000081c (0x40044403) x8  0x0000000000000000 mem 0x0000000000000400
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000820 (0x00147413) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000824 (0x02041463)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000828 (0xf1402473) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000082c (0x40044403) x8  0x0000000000000000 mem 0x0000000000000400
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000830 (0x00247413) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000834 (0x02041863)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000838 (0x10500073)
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000083c (0xfd9ff06f)

the remaining part from last loop =>
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000814 (0xf1402473) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000818 (0x10802023) mem 0x0000000000000100 0x00000000
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000081c (0x40044403) x8  0x0000000000000001 mem 0x0000000000000400
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000820 (0x00147413) x8  0x0000000000000001
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000824 (0x02041463)

This send to execution some another region =>
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000084c (0xf1402473) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000850 (0x10802223) mem 0x0000000000000104 0x00000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000854 (0x7b202473) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000858 (0x0ff0000f)
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000085c (0x0000100f)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000860 (0x30000067)

sent region 1 -> This two instruction is working and returning =>
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000300 (0x0440006f)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000344 (0x38803023) mem 0x0000000000000380 0x0000000000000000

sent region 2 -> in this time those are running =>
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000300 (0x0440006f)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000344 (0x7b241073) c1970_dscratch0 0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000348 (0x30102473) x8  0x800000000014112d
        core   0: 3 0x000000000000034c (0x38803023) mem 0x0000000000000380 0x800000000014112d
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000350 (0x7b202473) x8  0x0000000000000000

sent region 3 -> now it is completed like this and goes another region of debug rom =>
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000300 (0x0440006f)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000344 (0x0300006f)
                                    this is jumping from 344 to 374
                                    Then it is entering debug rom from  exception region.
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000808 (0x0380006f)
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000840 (0x7b202473) x8  0x0000000000000000
        core   0: 3 0x0000000000000844 (0x10002623) mem 0x000000000000010c 0x00000000


I didn't understand the part 0x3.. What they are doing?
The instruction at 0x344 is changing time to time. How and by whom those memory regions are changed (I checked and there is not any store operation to that(0x344) address)?
As I understand, the program starting from 0x800 to 0x870: DRETis debug rom. Is the region starting from0x300` to somewhere(IDK) program buffer? and does gdb or openOCD write some instructions to monitor data on registers and memory while a program is being debugged?

Since the spike creates big logs very fast I needed to enter all the commands quickly. So, I used a macro recorder and sped up. Any other method to play with RISC-V debug mode to understand is welcome.
